# Firebase Counting Number of Children for Message Number Count using numChildren()

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I am trying to count  how many message user has.

Right now i pull data with this:

```
  this.msgData = this.fire.authState.switchMap(auth => this.db.object(`messages/${auth.uid}`).valueChanges());
this.msgData.subscribe(msgdata =>{

console.log(msgdata);


});
```

output:
[image: msgkeys]

how to return number of those keys ? 
db is like:
[image: db]

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
Object.keys(msgdata).length
```

Comment: thanks.i feel like this is very inefficient way since just for counting number of keys i pull all data. is there any other way ?

Comment: You can do the following: Spin up a cloud function which listens for changes to that node and on every change it counts the children and updates some other node, say /messageCount/$uid, then you simply pull the count from there. I prefer this because the client won't have to do any work

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) for the purpose. Example:

```
this.msgData.subscribe(msgdata =>{

console.log(_.size(msgdata));

});
```